# Overlapping fragments when app resumed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this problem with overlapping fragments. I read other resolutions, but they seem to be over complicated as for problem like this. It happens when app is not used for sometime and then it's resumed or recreated and it seems that it remembers last fragment and creates the new one as if app have been destroyed last time.

Is that something related to `savedInstanceState`?

Code:

```
// used in onCreate()
private void setUpFragments(){
    Fragment fragment;

    switch (fragmentName){
        case CALLS:
            fragment = new CallLogsFragment();
            break;
        case CONTACTS:
            fragment = new ContactListFragment();
            break;
        case SETUP:
            fragment  = new SetupFragment();
            break;
        case REGISTER:
            fragment = new RegisterFragment();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new SetupFragment();
    }

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            .commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_calls:
            setFragment(new CallLogsFragment());

            break;
        case R.id.nav_contacts:
            setFragment(new ContactListFragment());

            break;
        case R.id.nav_add_contacts:
            setFragment(new AddContactsFragment());

            break;
        case R.id.nav_setup:
            setFragment(new SetupFragment());

            break;
        default:
            setFragment(new ContactListFragment());
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}

public void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After default you do not have 
***break;***

```
    default:
        fragment = new SetupFragment();
```

than it should be in both cases

```
    default:
        fragment = new SetupFragment();
        break;
```

You can check my code:

in the begging of the program (in onCreate)

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .add(FRAME_LAYOUT,
                    createFragment(defaultCurrentItem),
                    createItemDescription(defaultCurrentItem))
            .commit();
```

The function to begin transaction

```
private Fragment createFragment(int position){
    switch (position) {
        case BOT_NAV_POSITION_SETTINGS:
            return new SettingsFragment_();
        case BOT_NAV_POSITION_STATISTICS:
            return new StatisticsFragment_();
        case BOT_NAV_POSITION_MAIN:
            return new MainFragment_();
        case BOT_NAV_POSITION_FORTH:
            return new ForthFragment_();
        case BOT_NAV_POSITION_REMINDERS:
            return new ReminderFragment_();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

And later when you need to change fragment

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(FRAME_LAYOUT,
                        createFragment(position),
                        createItemDescription(position))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, setup the fragments(i.e call setupFragments) only if activity is newly created(i.e savedInstanceState == null).

On activity recreation, activity's fragment manager will restore its old state. If you didn't check for savedInstanceState, yours newly committed fragment and fragment manager's restored fragment will be overlapped.

Comment: Should I then save somehow this fragment to `savedInstanceState` - maybe on `onResume()`?

Comment: After you commit your fragment, activity's fragment manager keeps track of the committed fragments, current shown fragment,.. etc.... Activity itself takes care on saving/restoring its fragment manager state when it is recreated. You no need to anything explicitly.

Comment: Accept the answer, if it solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: As soon as I will get to the code I will check and then of course accept when I will thoroughly test it :)